# Transformation of normal distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose I have a normal distribution $A \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^{2})$ with a known cuttof point (percentile) on this distribution called $o$. Based on this point the distribution needs to be transformed which leads to a new distribution called $W$. Next, suppose $s$ equals a deterministic value. $o$ and $s$ are known in advance and do not need to be estimated.
 The first part of $A \in [-\infty,o]$ becomes deterministic and equal to $o+s$, the second part $]o,+\infty]$ remains stochastic and is equal to a transformation of $A$ more specifically $\mathcal{N}(\mu+s,\sigma^{2})$

So summarised:
$W = \begin{cases}o+s & \text{if } A \leq o \\ A+s & \text{if } A > o \end{cases}$

I want to find an expression for the pdf of $W$.

More specifically in my application A represents the arrival time distribution at a customer and $o$ represent the opening time at that customer. If you arrive to early you will have to wait before you can serve (service time is equal to $s$) the customer.

My current (unsuccesfull) solution approach for the case in which $\mu=10,\sigma=1,o=11,s=1$ is as follows
I think W is the component mix:
$W= P(A\leq o)*(o+s)+ P(A>o)*(A+s),$

I entered this in mathematica (see picture below)

Furthermore, I programmed a monte carlo simulation executing 100000 iterations. The new distribution has a mean equal to $12.08$ and a standard deviation equal to $0.26$.

[image]
[image]

Comment: $W$ has a censored Normal distribution (censored below at $c$). Then, the pdf of $W$ has a discrete mass at the point $c$, and a continuous component for $A > c$. This is not reflected in your plot above, and so your plot and working are faulty.

Comment: Also, how can you run a simulation (or make a plot) without specifying a value for $c$?

Comment: thanks for the remark, this was an error, there should be no $c$ variable only an $o$.

Comment: Instead of calculating the mean and standard deviation based on my simulation samples I now added a histogram of the actual samples to the post.

Comment: In the definition of $W$, what is the relationship between "$\mathcal{N}(\mu+s,\sigma^{2})$" and "$A$"?  Do these represent independent variables--as the notation suggests--or is the former indeed some "transformation" of $A$?  If the latter, exactly how is $A$ being transformed?

Comment: I don't actually see much of a question in here... but I presume your interest lies in estimating $\mu$ and possibly $\sigma^2$ for the original untruncated, untransformed $A$. I am also somewhat confident that in your formulation of $W$ you meant to write that $A=W$ when lower limit of detection is not reached. The pertinent question is whether you know $s$ in which case you can just add $s$ to $W$ and make this a simple EM algorithm application.

Comment: I understand the confusion because of my wrong notation. I meant a transformation of $A$ as the mean of $A$ is increased with $s$.

Comment: I don't know the correct notation. But it should be impossible to have a value smaller than $o+s$ as can be seen in the histogram.

Comment: @cevertje400 very well. However, please answer: are either $o$ or $s$ known here or must they be estimated from data? For instance, in the case of screening for CD4 count in HIV positive persons, we *know* that values lower than 400 are returned as "indeterminable", so the thresholding level is known.

Comment: Both $o$ and $s$ are known in advance. $o$ is the opening time of a customer and $s$ is the service which is assumed to be known in advance in my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't bring myself to use an 'a' or $A$ for a random variable (or an 'o' for a constant), so will swap for $X$ and $c$.

**The problem**

Let $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with pdf $f(x)$, and let $c$ and $s$ denote constants.

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/NormalNoramlpdfff.png))</sub>

Then, random variable $W$ has a censored distribution, where:

$$W = \begin{cases}c+s & \text{if } X \leq c \\ X+s & \text{if } X > c \end{cases}$$

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/censoredpluss.png))</sub>

The tail of $X$ to the left of $c$ becomes the discrete mass at $c+s$, with mass $P(X \leq c)$ (the blue point). The tail of $X$ to the right of $c$ gets shifted to $X+s$.

---

As to computation of $E[W]$:

Define:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/wcensor.png))</sub>

Then, $E[W]$ is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/expectwcensor.png))</sub>

where I am using the `Expect` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to automate the computation, and `Erf` denotes the error function.

For the given parameter values:

{$\mu$ -> 10, $\sigma$ -> 1, c -> 11, s -> 1}

... this yields:  $\frac{1}{2} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+23\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 e \pi }} \approx 12.0833$ as per OP's simulation.

**Suggestion**

The inclusion of constant $s$ is an unnecessary distraction. A neater way of modelling this is to define:

$$Y = \begin{cases}c & \text{if } X \leq c \\ X & \text{if } X > c \end{cases}$$

and $$W = Y + s$$

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I bought mathstatica now and copied your solution. But how did you draw the pdf of the censored distribution $W$ ?

Comment: Go to Chapter 2, Section 2.5 C - _Censored Distributions_ of the Rose/Smith book: see Figure 20. Figure 20 plots the distribution of $Y$ in my answer above. I just adapted that for your case (+s). To view the code that generated the figure, click on the little triangle under the diagram, ... |> Fig. 20  ... and the code will appear. If you want the actual code to generate the plot above, let me know and I can send it to you.